# Redirect batch file commands to a file

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I am in a situation to send all batch file commands to a text file. For example:

```
(
echo line one
echo line two
echo line three
) >> "script.txt"
```

instead of sending above commands output to script.txt, I want the file to contain:

```
echo line one
echo line two
echo line three
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Um... save them to the file? This feels unclear to me. Where exactly do you need to do this, and what exact problem are you facing in doing so? See https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask for some suggestions on how to write questions that are likely to result in useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for comment; try next code snippet:

```
(
echo echo line one
echo echo line two
echo echo line three
) >> "script.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't "redirecting" the commands, but if you're just trying to put the commands into a file, you can try this:

```
doskey /history >> script.txt
```